# Only return rows when there is only one value for a given column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a rather complex join query, whose results I only care about when there is a single distinct `Table_ID` value in the result.  For example, if there were multiple values for `Table_ID`, say 1 and 2.. I would want 0 rows returned.

I was thinking of doing this by adding `WHERE COUNT(DISTINCT Table_ID) = 1`.  Is that the best way to go about this?  Doing this through `LIMIT` doesn't seem possible because that would limit the number of rows I get returned from other tables beyond the one I intend to limit.

Using PHP/MySQL.

Comment: This question cannot be answered without seeing the full query you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I did this once by grouping on the `Table_ID` and then counting the number of items in the group. Something like:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS num FROM `myTable` GROUP BY `Table_ID` HAVING num = 1
```

More info: http://www.java2s.com/Code/SQL/Select-Clause/UseCOUNTGROUPandHAVING.htm

Comment: Won't grouping prevent me from getting the other rows when there are multiple rows with that same `Table_ID`?

Comment: Yes but you "only care about when there is a single distinct Table_ID value in the result", right??

Comment: Yes, it's possible to have multiple rows with only one distinct Table_ID